# SoftLayer Hardware API : Storage Operations on BareMetal Server

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

BareMetal Server with OS (Fast Provision) is running. On Running BM Server Is it possible to attach storage using REST API.
The storage can be of Portable Storage,iSCSI Storage.
If yes, please share the rest api details along with payloads for attaching/detach/delete of storage on BareMetal Server.

Answer (score 0):

Portable storages only can be attached to VSIs

iSCSI are attached manually see:
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/connect-iscsi-lun-linux-centosrhel-7

You also can access to block storages, but also that is manually see
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/block-storage-linux

by API you only can authorized the access for more information see [API for Performance and Endurance storage(Block storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454059/api-for-performance-and-endurance-storageblock-storage)