# API for Listing All Performance Storages for a user

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am new to softlayer. We need to have all the performance storages for a user so that by selecting any of these we can get corresponding Virtual Machine Id for authorizing with storage. Please help me as I am struggling in same for last 4-5 days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the following Rest request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,nasType,storageType, allowedVirtualGuests,billingItem[orderItem[id,order[id,userRecord.username]],description,location[id,longName]]]&objectFilter={   "networkStorage": {     "nasType": {       "operation": "ISCSI"     },     "billingItem": {       "description": {         "operation": "Block Storage (Performance)"       },       "orderItem": {         "order": {           "userRecord": {             "username": {               "operation": "myUsername"             }           }         }       }     }   } }

Method: GET
```

Where:
This request will help you to get `”Network Storage”` items filtered by `type` (Block Storage (Performance))     and `”username”`. Also to get valid available virtual guests to authorize, `”allowedVirtualGuests”`property was added in the object mask.

**Some references:**

[SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage)

[API for Performance and Endurance storage(Block storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454059/api-for-performance-and-endurance-storageblock-storage)

### Update 1:

The above request allows you to apply several filters according what you want. You only need to add/remove the filters according to your needs.
If you need associated storage volumes only by filtering “user”, some filters should be removed to the previous request, for example:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,nasType,storageType, billingItem[orderItem[id,order[id,userRecord.username]],description,location[id,longName]]]&objectFilter={   "networkStorage": {     "billingItem": {       "orderItem": {         "order": {           "userRecord": {             "username": {               "operation": "myUsername"             }           }         }       }     }   } }

Method: GET
```

Notice that all associated storage volumes are a set of: **File Storage, Block storage, Object Storage, Evault Backup**. If you want to a specific `Storage type`, you can add an additional filter.

Additionally, if you want only list **“Block Storage”** items filtered by **`user`**, you can use other method too:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage?objectFilter={   "iscsiNetworkStorage": {     "billingItem": {       "orderItem": {         "order": {           "userRecord": {             "username": {               "operation": "myUserName"             }           }         }       }     }   } }       

Method: GET
```

#### List “Filke Storage” items filtered by user:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNasNetworkStorage?objectFilter={   "nasNetworkStorage": {     "billingItem": {       "orderItem": {         "order": {           "userRecord": {             "username": {               "operation": "myUserName"             }           }         }       }     }   } }

Method: GET
```

References:

[SoftLayer_Account::getIscsiNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNasNetworkStorage)
[SoftLayer_Account::getNasNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage%5D)

Comment: I added some requests can help you. But, the first request I sent you previously should the basis to get the all `storage volumes` filtered per `user`.