# How to fetch LocationID, Storage Package ID, Storage Size ID and SnapShot Space Size ID for placing order in Endurance Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to implement placing order for endurance storage in my Application using **BPM over ICO (IBM Cloud Orchestrator)** dynamically.

I needed following parameters for creating rest call for placing order

1. Package to use
2. Storage Type
3. Location
4. Storage Package (IOPS/GB)
5. Storage Size
6. Snapshot Space Size
7. OS Type

   1. **Package to use:-**
      I already know package value for endurance is `240`.
   2. **Storage Type:-**
      For endurance storage what will be numeric id for endurance What rest 
      call will help in this..?
   3. **Location:-**
      This Rest call gives me locations ID:-

   **https:[username]:[apiKey]api.softlayer.com/rest
   /v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getRegions.json**

   4. **Storage Package:-**
      For Endurance I found only these **3 options in storage package** :-

      - 0.25 IOPS/GB
      - 2 IOPS/GB
      - 4 IOPS/GB

   How will I get id for these three..?

   5. **Storage Size:-**

   For storage size id I used a rest call :-

   **https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]&objectFilter={"items":{"prices":{"pricingLocationGroup":{"locations":{"item":{"operation":"loc_code"}}}}}}**

   Is there any other way..?

   6. **Snapshot Space Size:-**
      What will be the rest call for snapshot space size ids..?

   Please help me as I need to integrate this functionality as an **API using
   BPM**. We need to place order for endurance storage with dynamic values.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: See carefully the result of your request, it is already getting all the prices for IOPS, storage sizie, snapshot space etc. Please read documentation

Answer (score 0):

To get the valid prices for all **`configuration Endurance items`**, you can use [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices).

To know what package `Endurance` (PackageId = 240 ) is using, please see:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects

Method: GET
```

This is an example:

```
Package to use = 240
Storage Type: Endurance
Location: Dal06
Storage Package: 0.25 IOPS/GB
Storage Size: 40GB
Snapshot Space Size: 5GB
OS Type: Linux
```

**REST example:**

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "location": 154820, 
      "packageId": 240,
      "osFormatType": {
        "id": 12,
        "keyName": "LINUX"
      },
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 45058   # Endurance Storage
        },
        {
          "id": 45098   # Block Storage
        },
        {
          "id": 45068   # 0.25 IOPS per GB
        },
        {
          "id": 45148   # 40 GB Storage Space
        },
        {
          "id": 46120   # 5 GB Storage Snapshot Space
        }
      ],
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the above ids, we can use some filters for better understanding:

-Getting ** Storage Type**: `"id": 45058    # Endurance Storage`:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_service_enterprise"}}}}&objectMask=mask[id,categories,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]

Method: GET
```

Where we are filtering by : **`categoryCode`**

- Getting id  for “Block Storage” or “File Storage”, we choose **Block Storage**:

`"id": 45098    # Block Storage`

The filter will be changed to:

```
objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_block"}}}}
```

- Getting available ids for **Storage Package**:

i.e.: `"id": 45068 # 0.25 IOPS per GB`

The filter to use is: `"categoryCode": "storage_tier_level"`

```
objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_tier_level"}}}}&objectMask=mask[id,categories,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]
```

- Getting **Storage Size**:

Filter to use: `"categoryCode": "performance_storage_space"`

```
objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "performance_storage_space"}}}}&objectMask=mask[id,categories,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]
```

- Getting **Snapshot Space Size:**

Filter to use: `"categoryCode": "storage_snapshot_space"`

```
objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "storage_snapshot_space"}}}}
```

#### Some references:

[API for Performance and Endurance storage(Block storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454059/api-for-performance-and-endurance-storageblock-storage)