# How to find out the price details of any offering in softlayer to put it into API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Suppose I want to purchase a replica of Block storage. I have `scheduleId` & `data center Id` with me. How I can find out the price details to put into API while purchasing a replica.

Here,

I have parameters like:

```
placeorder = {
     "complextype": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
     "packageId": 216,
     "location": "AMSTERDAM",
     "originVolumeScheduleId": 123,
     "originVolumeId": 321,
     "prices": [
<Which parameters are necessary here & how we can choose those>
]
```

I need to know how we can find out the price details with `SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItems` method, but I am confused while selecting prices for any offering.

Answer (score 0):

When ordering a `replica`, we need to set the same items than ‘Primary’ and add a `Storage Replication` item.

For example, we have an`Endurance` with following configured items:

- Endurance Storage
- Block Storage
- 0.25 IOPS per GB
- 20 GB Storage Space
- 10 GB Storage Space (Snapshot Space)

To see these items through API using `StorageId`, please execute the following:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storageId]/getBillingItem?objectMask=mask[id,orderItem[id,description,itemPrice.id,order[id,items]]]

Method: GET
```

Now, to order a **`replica`**, we need to add **item prices** related to above listed items and add a `Storage Replication` item according to chosen `Location`.

This is an example to order a replica:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Note: 
Please change “verifyOrder” to “placeOrder” when your order is ready.
In my case, the location chosen is `PARIS`

Method: POST

Json Payload:


{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "location": "PARIS",
      "packageId": 240,
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
      "originVolumeId": 6465511,
      "originVolumeScheduleId": 33641,
      "osFormatType": {
        "id": 12,
        "keyName": "LINUX"
      },
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 147099     # 20 GB Storage Space (Storage Replication)
        },
        {
          "id": 45058     # Endurance Storage
        },
        {
          "id": 45068   # 0.25 IOPS per GB (Storage Tier Level)
        },
        {
          "id": 45098     # Block Storage 
        },
        {
          "id": 144009     # 20 GB Storage Space (Storage Space)
        },
        {
          "id": 143449     # 10 GB Storage Space (Storage Snapshot Space)
        }
      ],
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

To get valid prices according to `Endurance package` (packageId = 240), please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,locationGroupId,item[id,keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]

Method: GET
```

**Some References:**

[Location-based-Pricing-and-You](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You)

[SoftLayer_Product_Order](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order)

[SoftLayer_Network_Storage:getBillingItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getBillingItem)

[How to fetch LocationID, Storage Package ID, Storage Size ID and SnapShot Space Size ID for placing order in Endurance Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888453/how-to-fetch-locationid-storage-package-id-storage-size-id-and-snapshot-space)

I hope this information help you.