# how to create block storage using softlayer api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to create a performance block storage using python lib, but the response shows "Price does not have an id", what's the problem, am I missed any parameters.
This is the code to submit the request.

```
orderData = {
            "complexType": "Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Iscsi",
            "packageId": 222,
            "location": 154820,
            "quantity": 1,
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": 40678           
                },
                {
                    "id": space_id
                },
                {
                    "id": 40798
                },
            ],
            "osFormatType": {'createDate': '', 'keyName': 'LINUX', 'description': 'Use if your host operating system is Linux.', 'name': 'Linux', 'id': 12}
        }
response = productOrderService.verifyOrder(orderData)
```

I've list all prices for performance storage using python code, just list part info:

> ************PACKAGE:  Pkg Id: 222    OPTIONAL CATEGORY:
>       ----name: Surcharges  Cat Id: 315
>                      Item Price id:32082 Description: International Services  LocGrp Id:  none    OPTIONAL CATEGORY:
>       ----name: Performance Storage NFS  Cat Id: 378
>                      Item Price id:40668 Description: File Storage (Performance)  LocGrp Id:  none    OPTIONAL CATEGORY:
>       ----name: Storage Replication  Cat Id: 388    OPTIONAL CATEGORY:
>       ----name: Performance Storage iSCSI  Cat Id: 380
>                      Item Price id:40678 Description: Block Storage (Performance)  LocGrp Id:  none    REQUIRED CATEGORY:
>       ----name: Storage Space  Cat Id: 382
>                      Item Price id:82389 Description: 40 GB Storage Space  LocGrp Id: 509
>                      Item Price id:82395 Description: 80 GB Storage Space  LocGrp Id: 505
>                      Item Price id:90579 Description: 4000 GB Storage Space  LocGrp Id: 545
>                      Item Price id:90583 Description: 12000 GB Storage Space  LocGrp Id: 505
>                      Item Price id:90585 Description: 12000 GB Storage Space  LocGrp Id: 507
>                      Item Price id:90589 Description: 12000 GB Storage Space  LocGrp Id: 545

---

Also I checked other links:
[How to fetch LocationID, Storage Package ID, Storage Size ID and SnapShot Space Size ID for placing order in Endurance Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888453/how-to-fetch-locationid-storage-package-id-storage-size-id-and-snapshot-space?noredirect=1)
[API for Performance and Endurance storage(Block storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454059/api-for-performance-and-endurance-storageblock-storage#)
Not too much help info found.
Anyone can help to check the issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexType that you are using is not valid, you need to use this:

```
"complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Iscsi"
```

Here an example of orderData that I used:

```
orderData = {
             "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_PerformanceStorage_Iscsi",
            "packageId": 222,
            "location": 154820,
            "quantity": 1,
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": 40678           
                },
                {
                    "id": 40688
                },
                {
                    "id": 40798
                }
            ],
            "osFormatType": { 
                "keyName": "LINUX",
                "complexType": "SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi_OS_Type"

            }
          }
```

Regards

Comment: I can provision the performance storage after modified the file as you suggested, thanks a lot