# understanding undef locationGroupId entries in package items

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, iscsi

I ran a SL REST API query to get the list of items available for the 240 (Endurance iSCSI) package for only the common price entries, by querying only those price entries with a locationGroupId value of undefined.  Here is the query I ran:

curl -u : https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItems.json?objectFilter=%7B%22items%22:%7B%22prices%22:%7B%22locationGroupId%22:%7B%22operation%22:%22is%20null%22%7D%7D%7D%7D

I am a bit confused by the result.  Here is an excerpt:

...

```
   {
      "upgradeItemId" : null,
      "description" : "4000 GB Storage Space",
      "capacity" : "4000",
      "keyName" : "4000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE",
      "itemCategory" : {
         "quantityLimit" : 0,
         "name" : "Storage Space",
         "id" : 382,
         "categoryCode" : "performance_storage_space"
      },
      "softwareDescriptionId" : null,
      "id" : 5146,
      "itemTaxCategoryId" : 166,
      "prices" : [
         {
            "recurringFee" : "58",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 386831,
                  "itemPriceId" : 46625
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 46625,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "145",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 385796,
                  "itemPriceId" : 46096
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 46096,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "290",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 385806,
                  "itemPriceId" : 46106
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 46106,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "290",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 383598,
                  "itemPriceId" : 45364
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 45364,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "362.5",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 386841,
                  "itemPriceId" : 46635
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 46635,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "435",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 385816,
                  "itemPriceId" : 46116
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 46116,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "580",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 383608,
                  "itemPriceId" : 45374
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 45374,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "580",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 1302339,
                  "itemPriceId" : 183991
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 183991,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "725",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 386851,
                  "itemPriceId" : 46645
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 46645,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "1015",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 383618,
                  "itemPriceId" : 45384
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 45384,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "1450",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 1300099,
                  "itemPriceId" : 181751
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 181751,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         },
         {
            "recurringFee" : "1682",
            "setupFee" : "0",
            "quantity" : null,
            "packageReferences" : [
               {
                  "packageId" : 240,
                  "id" : 1295927,
                  "itemPriceId" : 178645
               }
            ],
            "onSaleFlag" : null,
            "oneTimeFee" : "0",
            "itemId" : 5146,
            "sort" : 10,
            "currentPriceFlag" : null,
            "laborFee" : "0",
            "id" : 178645,
            "locationGroupId" : null
         }
      ],
      "units" : "GB"
   },
...
```

For this item, "4000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE", there are multiple price ids that have a locationGroupId of undefined.  The only thing I can see as different are the recurringFee value.  I don't understand which of these prices objects to choose.  It seems I should just choose the cheapest one, but I assume there is some other difference, but I don't know what it is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those prices have different **categories**, for example they can be:

- Performance Storage Replication
- Storage Snapshot Space
- Storage Space
- Storage Replication

You need to use the price according the order that you would like to placed, also you need to consider the capacity for these prices (**capacityRestrictionMaximum** and **capacityRestrictionMinimum** properties)

To get this kind information, you need to add a mask like the below rest request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItems.json?objectFilter={"items":{"prices":{"locationGroupId":{"operation":"is null"}}}}&objectMask=mask[prices[categories]]

Method: Get
```

Encoding:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItems.json?objectFilter=%7B%22items%22%3A%7B%22prices%22%3A%7B%22locationGroupId%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22is+null%22%7D%7D%7D%7D&objectMask=mask%5Bprices%5Bcategories%5D%5D

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [API for Performance and Endurance storage(Block
  storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454059/api-for-performance-and-endurance-storageblock-storage)

Comment: Hmm, that seems a little unclear to me.  I don't see anything in the price JSON stanza that indicates a category type.  The category seems to be at the higher level object for the 4000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE keyName and the itemCategory stanza.

Comment: The category that you are seeing is from the item, you need to get these for the prices, please try the request that I provided