# JSON validation not working

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to use the `SoftLayer_Product_Order/<package>/verifyOrder.json` API to validate my JSON for ordering some Endurance NAS, but for many combinations.

I keep getting the error:

> **Order is missing the following category: Storage Space**

But I seem to be providing a valid Storage Space type price.

The Combination of price objects are:

```
Type: 45064 (Endurance Storage)
IOPS: 45074 (LOW_INTENSITY_TIER) 
Storage: 45856 (20 GB Storage Space) 
Base Type: 45104 (Block Storage)
```

**JSON:**

```
{    "parameters" : [
      {
         "location" : "449494",
         "packageId" : 240,
         "osFormatType" : {
            "id" : 12,
            "keyName" : "LINUX"
         },
         "complexType" : "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
         "quantity" : 1,
         "prices" : [
            {
               "id" : "45064"
            },
            {
               "id" : "45074"
            },
            {
               "id" : "45856"
            },
            {
               "id" : "45104"
            }
         ]
      }    
    ] 
 }
```

**REST call:**

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/240/verifyOrder.json
```

**Response:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'error' => 'Order is missing the following category: Storage Space.',
          'code' => 'SoftLayer_Exception_Order_MissingCategory'
        };
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: The link is the url part of a rest call.  I have changed it to a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake to define the price for storage, you are sending a **size for Snapshot and not for the block endurance**

> - **Price**: 45856 **Category**: Storage Snapshot Space
> - **Price**: 45124 **Category**: Storage Space

So you need to use the price belongs to **"Storage Space" (45124)**, a request that could be help to identify them should be:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"name":{"operation":"Storage Space"}}}}&objectMask=mask[categories]

Method: Get
```

Try this please:

```
{  
    "parameters":[  
        {  
            "location":"449494",
            "packageId":240,
            "osFormatType":{  
                "id":12,
                "keyName":"LINUX"
            },
            "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
            "quantity":1,
            "prices":[  
                {  
                    "id":"45064"
                },
                {  
                    "id":"45074"
                },
                {  
                    "id":"45124"
                },
                {  
                    "id":"45104"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to

[understanding undef locationGroupId entries in package items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576183/understanding-undef-locationgroupid-entries-in-package-items)

answers this question for me.